# Subquery on HAVING clause don't work?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have two tables, one that refers to the GRADES of the students and the other that refers to the info of the STUDENTS, those two tables are connected by the attributes `STUDENTS.ST_ID` and `GRADES.G_STUDENTS`. The query ask me to retrieve all the students whose average mark is higher that the average mark of a student with a particular `STUDENTS.ST_ID_NUM` (another attribute for the matricule). I can retrieve the everage marks of all the students as:

```
SELECT STUDENTS.ST_NAME, STUDENTS.ST_SURNAME, AVG(GRADES.G_GRADE)  
FROM STUDENTS INNER JOIN GRADES  
ON STUDENTS.ST_ID = GRADES.G_STUDENT  
GROUP BY STUDENTS.ST_NAME, STUDENTS.ST_SURNAME;`
```

and the average mark of the particular student with a specific STUDENTS.ST_ID_NUM`:

```
select avg(grades.g_grade)   
from students inner join grades  
on students.st_id = grades.g_student  
where students.st_id_num = '061RDB121';
```

How I can put the condition on the first query? If I put another subquery in the `HAVING` clause don't work! I thought that an inner query could work, but I don't know how write it.

Comment: Show us the `HAVING` query that doesn't work, and tell us what the error message is.

Answer (score 4):

like this should work;

```
SELECT STUDENTS.ST_NAME, STUDENTS.ST_SURNAME, AVG(GRADES.G_GRADE)
FROM STUDENTS INNER JOIN GRADES
ON STUDENTS.ST_ID = GRADES.G_STUDENT
GROUP BY STUDENTS.ST_NAME, STUDENTS.ST_SURNAME;
having  AVG(GRADES.G_GRADE) > (select avg(grades.g_grade)
                                          from students inner join grades
                                            on students.st_id = grades.g_student
                                            where students.st_id_num = '061RDB121');
```

Answer (score 3):

You pretty much just put those 2 together,

```
SELECT STUDENTS.ST_NAME, STUDENTS.ST_SURNAME, AVG(GRADES.G_GRADE)
FROM STUDENTS INNER JOIN GRADES
ON STUDENTS.ST_ID = GRADES.G_STUDENT
GROUP BY STUDENTS.ST_NAME, STUDENTS.ST_SURNAME
HAVING AVG(GRADES.G_GRADE)>
    (
    select avg(grades.g_grade)
    from students inner join grades
    on students.st_id = grades.g_student
    where students.st_id_num = '061RDB121'
     )
```

;

Comment: I think this is what the OP was trying to say doesn't work... Mind you the docs say it should anyway =)

Comment: Ok now works, really I've tried this solution before ask here. The mistery of the life :/

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use your two queries combined?

```
SELECT STUDENTS.ST_NAME, STUDENTS.ST_SURNAME, AVG(GRADES.G_GRADE)
FROM STUDENTS INNER JOIN GRADES
ON STUDENTS.ST_ID = GRADES.G_STUDENT
GROUP BY STUDENTS.ST_NAME, STUDENTS.ST_SURNAME
HAVING AVG(GRADES.G_GRADE) > (
    select avg(grades.g_grade)
    from students inner join grades
    on students.st_id = grades.g_student
    where students.st_id_num = '061RDB121';
);
```